# iPhone UIImage rotate and then animate doesnt work

Tags: ios, image, animation, rotation

I am a novice to iPhone programming. I am trying to rotate an UIImage, and then animate it to a different location on the screen afterwards. The animation itself works fine (it displays the animation allright), but when combined with the rotation first, the image never shows up on the screen. Here's the code snippet:

---

```
// degrees to rotate animal:
int degreesToRotateAnimal = arc4random_uniform(360);

// create animal:
IBOutlet UIImageView *Animal = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Animal.png"]];
Animal.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 100, 20);
Animal.hidden = NO;

// rotate animal:  
Animal.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRotateAnimal * (PI / 180.0));

// add animal to subview:
[self.view addSubview:Animal];

// animate animal after rotation:
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                    delay:1
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
               animations:^{
                 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 70);
                 Animal.transform = transform;
               }
               completion:nil];

// commit: 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

As I said, nothing happens at all: Image is not rotated (I guess) and no animation is shown. However, if I omit the rotation, the animation goes fine and the image is shown perfectly. Can anybody help me out ?

Thanks!

Comment: In which method have you written this code ?

Comment: The `[UIView commitAnimations];` here is no use, it is for another way to do animations using `[UIView beginAnimations]`

Comment: You code works for me, when I implement it on `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Hi. It's a timer invocation that calls the method of rotating and moving the image above. I.e. after X (random) amount of time, the image is rotated and then moved (at least that's the idea).

Comment: I know, that's what it does on my test-project... Are you sure, this portion of code gets called ?